# Making a Tab control system smaller

Tags: usability, gui-design, wpf

Below is the desktop UI that I'm currently working on and I need to make it much smaller. It is 1266px wide and my task is to make something that is maximum 390 wide. I've been trying to look up UI designs for choosing categories but nothing is jumping out to me or they are mobile designs.

[image: current ui]

My current thought is to have a bubble system where you hover over the bubble and it expands from there but I'm not sure if that's just rubbish UI as it could go to 3 levels and may not be user friendly.

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a left hand side list menu for each of your tab items. And clicking on list menu item will open respective tab content. Its just a vertical arrangement of tab, but to ensure tab titles (now list menus) are not written vertically.

Comment: This turned out to be the best use of the space! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An accordion dropdown list could be a useful design pattern to use?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could include a tab bar with arrows to scroll left/right, and a dropdown list to provide quick, scrollable access with many items, as well as any functions like 'close all'. This is used by Firefox:

[image]